# Rewrite rule for nodejs app with subdomain on shared hosting

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I am trying to run a nodejs application on shared hosting and successfully installed node/npm following this tutorial from A2Hosting:

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts

I am now on INTEGRATING A NODE.JS APPLICATION WITH THE WEB SERVER part and when I copied the rewrite rules to the .htaccess file, it runs the node on the root domain instead of the wordpress website. Here is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN Node
# RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:49876/ [P,L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:49876/$1 [P,L]
# END Node
```

I wanted the nodejs app to run on the subdomain like: subdomain.domain.com and keep the wordpress running on: domain.com

What changes should I make to the nodejs rewrite rule to make it run on subdomain.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am trying to run a Angular/nodejs app from within a wordpress site on a2hosting and can only get it working by using the 30000 port in my url. I'd like to rewrite it so that I can use a subdomain in the url instead. Sounds very similar to what you were trying to do.

Comment: @SherriM Hi. This may be very late but my solution was to create a subdomain which automatically creates a folder within your root directory isolated from the wordpress site. That way, you can create your own .htaccess without conflicts. My root structure is like this:
 root > wp site, node site, other sites.

Comment: There is another problem that I'm currently stuck though. I'm still figuring out how to run a script which runs my node app everytime my server restarts during maintenance.

Comment: Thanks @RendellLasola. We ended up getting a VPS instead of using shared hosting, to have more control/flexibility. For your second problem, I used a cron job that checked to see if the node process was running and if not, started it up.  I no longer have the script, but there were plenty of examples online. good luck!